# Passport with Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm following this guide for implementing Passport for signup:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Everything works well, except that Passport does not redirect on successful signup. This is my code that I'm using to redirect on a successful signup:

```
//  POST        /signup
router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect : '/signup',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

I have verified that the user is created in the database. failureRedirect works! It's just on successRedirect that the web page hangs like it's not being successfully redirected.

Is there an incompatibility issue with passport and Express 4 Router? I see all examples of Passport using app.post() instead of router.post().

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're deviating from the tutorial in that you're using `successRedirect` to go to a page called `dashboard`, not `profile`. Have you updated your `app/routes.js` file to reflect that ? `app.get('/dashboard', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {...}`

Comment: Yes, you are right... the config error was in my route, not in passport!! ugh!! Thank you for helping me to think and check that!! :)